# query storage to front-end

Tags: pallet, storage, substrate-front-end, map

In the pallet-template, I have this storage:

```
#[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn getscoreboard)]
    pub(super) type ScoreBoard<T: Config> = StorageMap
        <_, Twox64Concat, T::AccountId, BoardInfo<T>>;
```

And in frontend file:
I tried 3 ways, but all didn't work

```
 api.query.pallet_template.scoreBoard.map((entry) => { console.log("Handle UPDATE2:", entry) })
```

```
 api.query.pallet_template.scoreBoard.entries().map((entry) => { console.log("Handle UPDATE2:", entry) })
```

```
const result = api.query.pallet_template.scoreBoard.entries()
result.map((entry) => { console.log("Handle UPDATE2:", entry) })
```

(Note that in the Balances.js `api.query.system.account.multi(addresses, balances` still works)

The error is "... map is not a function". I also tried with Object.key but it even doesn't log.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- it needs an `.entries()` first
- the `await` is missing

```js
let scores = await api.query.pallet_template.scoreBoard.entries();
scores.map(console.log);
```

Comment: Hi. I updated my question. With await, I tried but "Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (32:22)"

Comment: you are probably calling it inside a non-async function. Either convert your function to async one or try to unwrap the promise with `then()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Please test your code here: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/js after selecting your local development node on the left dropdown. Copy & pasting my answer should work.